# Typescript: Generic type in base class

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have the following code as a reduced example:

```
class QueryArgs {
  studentId?: string;
  teacherId?: string;
}

class BaseValidator<T> {
  protected args: T;

  constructor(args: T) {
    this.args = args;
  }

  protected requireTeacher(): void {
    if (!this.args.teacherId) {
      throw new Error("teacherId required");
    }
  }
}

class QueryValidator extends BaseValidator<QueryArgs> {
  public validateAdmin(): QueryArgs {
    this.requireTeacher();
    return this.args;
  }
}

// Recreated implementation from a third party library
const args: QueryArgs = new QueryArgs();
args.studentId = "XXXX-XXX-XXX";

// Not the actual implementation just for illustration
const validator = new QueryValidator(args);
const validArgs = validator.validateAdmin();
```

The problem that I am having is in the `BaseValidator` class in the `requireTeacher` method `this.args.teacherId` has the error `Property 'teacherId' does not exist on type 'T'`.

I am not sure what I am missing in the generics part of Typescript.

Ideally TS would know in the `BaseValidator` that the `args` is an instance of `QueryArgs`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to further constrain the generic type argument `T` to a type that has a `teacherId` property. The way it is now, any type can be passed as `T`, which means you can't assume that `T` has `teacherId`.

To constrain the type, try changing `class BaseValidator<T>` to `class BaseValidator<T extends QueryArgs>`. This restricts `T` to types that extends `QueryArgs` so that you're guaranteed that `T` has a `teacherId` property.

Check out this article where it mentions constraining generic arguments using `extends`: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html